# How do i fix a "Request failed with status code BadRequest" RestSharp

Tags: c#, request, restsharp

Im trying to send a post request but everytime it gives me " Request failed with status code BadRequest" how do i fix this error i have tried stuff like adding headers but i still got the same error

```
 var client = new RestClient(options);
       var request = new RestRequest()
           .AddQueryParameter("address", "jioaksiokar@cutradition.com")
           .AddQueryParameter("password", "aasfasdasdsf");
       var response = await client.PostAsync<MyResponse>(request);
       Console.WriteLine(response);
```

if you know how to fix it please tell me ty

Comment: If the response body contains details of the problem, you need to inspect them. If it doesn't, you stand no hope and we even less, because we have no way of knowing what **every possible server in the world** may use as a reason for returning a Bad Request response.

Comment: Its hard to tell from your code what's going wrong. What are the options you used for the client? what is the url? you seem to POST your request with stringQuery parameters which are not often used to pass data. what is the other side of the request? bad request can tell you that something went wrong on the other side but without seeing the other side of the request and the body and options used its not easy to say...

Comment: By convention, bad request (HTTP status 400) means there's something wrong with your request, for example it may be missing a required field, or a field might contain the wrong sort of data (e.g. a string where an integer was expected). Unfortunately API authors don't always follow the conventions and could return any status for any reason. Do you have access to the source code or documentation for the API you're trying to call? If you have the source code, have you tried debugging it in Visual Studio or some other IDE to see where the status is being set?

Comment: ty i fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this example helps you.

```
        public async Task<JsonResult> CallApi(
        string serverAddress,
        string apiAddress,
        string body
        )
    {

        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(serverAddress)
        };

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json-patch+json"));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add($"Authorization", $"Basic [write your encoded password here]");

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiAddress);
        request.Content = new StringContent(body,
                                            Encoding.UTF8,
                                            "application/json-patch+json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(jsonString);

    }
```

and then call it like this

```
                        dynamic array =
                        new[]
                        {
                            new {
                                op = "add",
                                path = "/fields/System.Title",
                                from = (string) null,
                                value = "test1"
                            },
                            new {
                                op = "add",
                                path = "/fields/System.Description",
                                from = (string) null,
                                value = "test2"
                            },
                            new {
                                op = "add",
                                path = "/fields/System.History",
                                from = (string) null,
                                value = "test3"
                            },
                            new {
                                op = "add",
                                path = "/fields/System.AssignedTo",
                                from = (string) null,
                                value = "test4"
                            }
                        };

                    JsonResult jsonResult = new ApiWorks().CallAzureApi(
                        @"http://127.0.0.1/",
                        @"project1/_apis/wit/workitems/$User Story?api-version=6.0",
                        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array)
                        );
```